# Unwanted vertical space in latex beamer with tcolorbox boxes

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I've just updated my TeX distribution and I realized that the last version of the `tcolorbox` package leads to an undesirable vertical space in my beamer presentations. In particular, There is too much vertical space at the top of the first box in a frame. I ignore whether this issue arises in other contexts too.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\DeclareTColorBox{mybox}{ O{red} m d"" !O{} }
{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of the frame}
Text text text text
\begin{mybox}{Box one} 
Hello world!
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Box two} 
Hello world!
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I used to get with older versions:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `before={}` in the `tcolorbox` options?

Comment: Yes, thank you, with the `before` and `after` options I can control the space before and after the boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\tcbsetforeverylayer{autoparskip}`.

In v4.40, `tcolorbox` changes the default vertical spaces added before and after colored boxes. The above code restores to the behavior until v4.32. For more info, see [`tcolorbox#115`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/115) and [`tcolorbox#121`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/121).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, this is what I thought.